# can't find error in this javascript code

Tags: javascript

it's not even running. Something is wrong with the do while loop. I'm assuming it's something with all the if statements? If someone could help me out i'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

```
        do {
        entry = prompt("Enter taxable income as a valid number\n" +
                       "Or enter 99999 to end entries", 99999);
        entry = parseInt(entry);

        // calculate the tax owed here
        if (entry < 0){
            document.write("Please enter a positive number");
        }
        if (entry > 0 && entry < 8701){
            tax_owed = entry * 0.10;
        }
        if (entry > 8700 && entry < 35351){
            tax_owed = 870 * 0.15;
            tax_owed += entry;
        }
        if (entry > 35350 && entry < 85651){
            tax_owed = 4867 * 0.25;
            tax_owed += entry;
        }
        if (entry > 85650 && < 178651){
            tax_owed = 17442 * 0.28;
            tax_owed += entry;
        }
        if (entry > 178650 && entry < 388351){
            tax_owed = 43482 * 0.33;
            tax_owed += entry;
        }
        if (entry > 388350){
            tax_owed = 112683 * 0.35;
            tax_owed += entry;
        }

        alert("Tax owed is " + tax_owed);
    }
    while (entry != 99999);
```

Comment: What are those magic numbers? Why not assign them to variables? By refactoring your code you'll probably find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error of missing operand before `< 178651` is already found, but in case you want your code to have less potential errors, i suggest a light refactoring procedure.

- Using `else if` will be more efficient. Once found a block that corresponds to a given `entry` value, the program will stop checking other conditions. Moreover, you will have to specify just those values which divides your range (your "milestones"), instead of repeating them like `entry < 8701` followed by `entry > 8700`. Finally, it wil **fix other bug** which is printing `tax_owed = ..something like 140000..` when you enter 99999.
- Changing the condition of the loop (introducing a boolean variable) would be more readable.
- I'm not a tax man at all, but are you sure you want to add `tax_owed += entry;` ? I mean, do i really owe $10130.5 when declaring $10000? In any case, it will be more readable to have 1 line instead of 2: `tax_owed = entry + 17442 * 0.28; // but do you really add 'entry'?`.

So, the code will be something like this:

```
continueEntering = true;

while ( continueEntering ) {
    tax_owed = 0;
    entry = prompt("Enter taxable income as a valid number\n" + "Or enter 99999 to end entries", 99999);
        entry = parseInt(entry);

    if (entry == 99999) {
        continueEntering = false;
    } else if (entry < 0){
        alert("Please enter a positive number"); 
    } else if (entry <= 8700){
        tax_owed = entry * 0.10;
    } else if (entry <= 35350){
        tax_owed = 870 * 0.15 + entry;
    } else if (entry <= 85650){
        tax_owed = 4867 * 0.25 + entry;
    } else if (entry <= 178650){
        tax_owed = 17442 * 0.28 + entry;
    } else if (entry <= 388350){
        tax_owed = 43482 * 0.33 + entry;
    } else {
        tax_owed = 112683 * 0.35 + entry;
    }

    alert("Tax owed is " + tax_owed);
}
```

As said in comments, it's really better not to use the values themselves inside the body of your loop. It will be way easier to change one day those values, if they are stored in variables. here you can use 2 arrays. You can call them, say, `thresholds[]` and `tax_percentage[]`, or whatever (you know it better than me). The good thing of using arrays is that you'll be able to replace the sequence of `if` statements by just one `for` loop inside your original `while` loop.

================  UPDATE ====================

Here is how you can refactor the above code to use a `for` loop instead of lots of `if`.

```
continueEntering = true;

while ( continueEntering ) {
    tax_owed = 0;
    exitValue = 99999;

    tax_threshold = [ 0, 8700, 35350, 85650, 178650, 388350 ];
    tax_rate = [ 0.10, 0.15, 0.25, 0.28, 0.33, 0.35 ];
    additional_tax = [ 0, 870, 4867, 17442, 43482, 112683 ];

    entry = prompt("Enter taxable income as a valid number\n" + 
        "Or enter " + exitValue + " to end entries", exitValue);
    entry = parseInt(entry);

    if (entry == exitValue) {
        continueEntering = false;
    } else if (entry < 0){
        alert("Please enter a positive number"); 
    } else {

        for( i = tax_threshold.length-1; i >= 0; i-- ) {
            if ( entry > tax_threshold[i] ) {
                tax_owed = entry - tax_threshold[i];
                tax_owed *= tax_rate[i];
                tax_owed += additional_tax[i];
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    alert("Tax owed is " + tax_owed.toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: that looks a lot better. I have basic understandings of arrays and for loops but didnt even think about using them in this case. I am having a little trouble understanding this part of the for loop, though

i = tax_threshold.length-1; i >= 0; i--

I know how to read it Im just not sure how its applying. Why i-- and not i++? And what does the -1 do at the end of tax_threshold.length do?

Comment: @user3733575 , good questions. Well, -1 is just because when your array `a` has 6 elements, `a.length` is equal to 6, whereas to access the array elements, you need to start from 0: a[0] for the first element, then a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5]. That's why we use `length-1` for the last element.

Comment: Now, `for( i = tax_threshold.length-1; i >= 0; i-- )` means that we simply **reverse** the order of the loop: we start from the i=5, and go down to i=0. Why? It is more convenient in this particular tax problem. You see, you are trying to locate `entry` to one of the ranges. The upper limit of the range N is the lower limit for the range N+1. But what about the last range? It doesn't have an upper limit! So, we can represent all 6 ranges as: [more than 0], [more than 8700], ... , [more than 388350].

Comment: ok I got everything you were saying except this part: "The upper limit of the range N is the lower limit for the range N+1. But what about the last range? It doesn't have an upper limit! So, we can represent all 6 ranges as: [more than 0], [more than 8700], ... , [more than 388350]."

thanks for your help

Comment: But this approach will be incorrect when looping from the lowest `tax_threshold` to the highest. In this case, **every positive** value of `entry` will be located in the [more than 0] range. But if we're checking **in the reverse order**, first `if( entry > 388350 )` will select **only entries greater than 388350**. And `break` is very important here: it exits from the `for` loop once you've located an `entry`. But if `entry` is 200000, the above given condition will give `false`, and we'll pass to the next: `if (entry > 178650)`, and it will give `true`. Tell me if it's clear.

Comment: Yep, it's a bit tricky. Actually, your ranges are: [0; 8700), [8700; 35350), [35350; 85650), etc. But this will **duplicate** your threshold values. That's why, in order to avoid this duplication (potential source of bugs), we just draw those THRESHOLDS on the paper, and start thinking: are we interested in what is **to the left** or **to the right** of thresholds? Given that the last range is [388350; infinity), we realise that it's **from the right** that we have to loop. And from the right means from the highest tax_threshold to the lowest.

Comment: ok i understand what the code is doing. The for loop is using multiple arrays and starting at the last item in each of those arrays. However I still don't understand why the arrays NEED to start at the end (or why thats the more proper way for this project).

Comment: Well, if you want, even the **tax philosophy** tells us: "if someone declares MORE THAN 388350, his rate is 35%. OTHERWISE (else if), "if he declares MORE THAN 178650, rate is 33%", etc. But if you start from the left, it will give "if he declares MORE THAN 0, rate is 10%", which will give you 10% rate even for earnings like 100000000. You see? Just try drawing a little scheme on the paper, it will help understanding the logic.

Comment: "Given that the last range is [388350; infinity), we realise that it's from the right that we have to loop. And from the right means from the highest tax_threshold to the lowest"

Got it. But couldn't you also do a for loop that starts at the beginning and checks if the entry is greater than [i], if it is, it does the calculations and if it isn't, do i++?

Comment: oh wait i think i understand now. Since the entry needs to be between 2 numbers, you have to start from highest and work your way down. Right?

Comment: exactly! Well done. **between two numbers** is the point here. Normally, that's it, but you don't have a 2nd point for the LAST interval. So instead of using **two numbers** for describing each interval, we use **one number and a ">" sign**, paying attention to the order of the loop.

Comment: ok so why is it so bad to describe each interval with two numbers?

Comment: @user3733575 Good question. it's probably easier for beginners to see `if (entry > 8700 && entry < 35350)`, but i think you've realized the power of storing your data in arrays, and the only place you have your numbers, is at the beginning of the program. This is waaaay more maintainable and bug-safe. Now, you could really use `if (entry > tax_threshold[i] && entry < tax_threshold[i+1])`. But you don't have the 2nd number for the last interval, so you would have to loop 5 times (not 6), and check the 6th interval manually with `if` after your `for` loop. Personally, i would avoid such things.

Comment: i see your difficulties at this points, and probably you think it complicates your life, but, really, once you understand this power of generalization, you will easily use it. It's really better. What if you had not 6, but 56 intervals? Would you code 56 `if` blocks? And 506? The interest of programming is to automatize repetitive tasks. It's okay, continue coding, it will come with practise ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your 21 line

```
if (entry > 85650 && < 178651){ // there is no operand between && and <.
```

I think it should be

```
if (entry > 85650 && entry< 178651){
```

Answer (score 1):

On the line `if (entry > 85650 && < 178651)` if you look closely will see that you are not comparing the second number to anything. It should be `if (entry > 85650 && entry < 178651)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the proper to way calculate the taxes. You guys were right. I was way off. I'm using the 2012 income tax policy because that's what my professor wanted us to use. Thanks everyone for the help again. I'm really liking this site! Great for us n00bs.

```
    var tax_owed = 0;
    var entry;

    continueEntering = true;

    while (continueEntering) {
        tax_owed = 0;
        entry = prompt("Enter taxable income as a valid number\n" + "Or enter 99999 to end entries", 99999);
        entry = parseInt(entry);

        if (entry == 99999) {
            continueEntering = false;
        } else if (entry < 0){
            alert("Please enter a positive number"); 
        } else if (entry <= 8700){
            tax_owed = entry * 0.10;
        } else if (entry <= 35350){
            tax_owed = entry - 8700;
            tax_owed *= 0.15;
            tax_owed += 870;
        } else if (entry <= 85650){
            tax_owed = entry - 35350;
            tax_owed *= 0.25;
            tax_owed += 4867;
        } else if (entry <= 178650){
            tax_owed = entry - 85650;
            tax_owed *= 0.28;
            tax_owed += 17442;
        } else if (entry <= 388350){
            tax_owed = entry - 178650;
            tax_owed *= 0.33;
            tax_owed += 43482;
        } else if (entry > 388350){
            tax_owed = entry - 388350;
            tax_owed *= 0.35;
            tax_owed += 112683;
        }

        alert("Tax owed is " + tax_owed.toFixed(2));
```

}

Comment: As you can see, in `else if (entry <= 8700)` block you have only 1 line, while the other 5 cases have 3 lines of tax calculation in them. But what if we try to make that first block look like others? From your code we see, that you first **substract the value of the previous "threshold"** (thus making it appear 2 times in the code, which is dangerous source of bugs. But what is the threshold **before** the 1st block, before 8700? Well it is 0! So, we can add `tax_owed = entry - 0` there, which will allow you to re-write the next line as `tax_owed *= 0.10` (`tax_owed` was equal to `entry`).

Comment: Finally, you can add `tax_owed += 0` which will not change its value, but from now on all of your 6 blocks have exactly the same format! It means that we can create 3 arrays by 6 elements and use `for` instead of 6 `if` blocks. Just check out how EASY and SAFE (no bugs) it is, from now on, to change some values or to add/remove some "tax thresholds"! Hope you've got it. See my main answer (accepted one) for a new code added in the end.